# Java web UI - where to start to build a modern web-site?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, struts2, web

I acknowledge this question as broad and vague, but I would like to know from those with Web-UI experience in Java..

When you get a task to build a web application, like a web site (for example, e-store) what framework is a good start to get in touch with up-to-date Java web technologies?

The question is not about which framework is better and why, the question is: if you want to learn the common and **modern** ways of building web-ui application with Java, where is best to start to pick the essentials of building scalable and reliable web applications that can grow from a start-up site with a few pages to huge applications with hundreds of connections per second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) should get you up and running in no time and will automatically make you use Spring Framework, Spring MVC, Spring WebFlow, JSP, JSTL, JPA, AspectJ, etc etc.

I personally use Roo to get the foundations in, then I "un-Roo" my project and carry on about my business extending the project the way I need to.

Comment: The problem with Roo in my case is that it does a lot of things behind the scene, so when I tried it, I could not understand what was happening when it generated and generated something.

Comment: @EugeneP I updated my answer. I felt the same way, so when I was comfortable enough with Spring MVC on my own, I went away from Roo, but it was a good head start.

Answer (score 2):

There's lot of good choices:  Spring MVC, GWT, Grails, Roo   (notice how I deliberately left out JSF?).  It really depends on how comfortable you are with various parts of the language.  Grails and Roo will do a lot for you in all layers of your application, assuming you following conventions.  GWT will keep you out of ugly html and javascript for the most part.  Spring MVC is very unintrusive, and mostly acts as a dispatcher and binder, leaving all the nitty gritty details of views, persistence, etc... to the coder.

There's no right answer to this question, it all depends on what you want to do, how flexible it needs to be, etc....

Answer (score 1):

Well, two more possibilities for start a new Web project:

- To choose of the [Maven archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/usage.html) availables.
- Take a look to [AppFuse](http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart) (it uses maven also). AppFuse light is better for first contact.

I am not saying they are the best options, but it is good to know they exist.

Answer (score 1):

I think that web applications are getting richer and richer in the browser side of things, and that the server components are getting smaller. That is to say, the MVC pattern is taking on more significance in the browser, so this has had the effect of minimizing the need to preserve and track state on the server.

So the most relevant question isn't, perhaps, modern ways of building web applications using Java, but rather modern ways of build web applications *overall*. But if you were to only focus on the Java piece, you'd see a shift from MVC more towards REST-style data-centric services. Whether that's the REST annotations in Spring MVC or a more "pure" JAX-RS implementation (and there are quite a few), the little state that the server ends up keeping is a security context.

In terms of sheer scalability, that comes with design and appropriate granularity of those data-centric services. Of course there are the basics on the server itself (shared resources such as connection pools, thread pools, database tuning), but those aren't anything particularly new.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general for StackOverflow.

Epic comparison from Wikipedia - [Comparison of web application frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks)

Comment: Agreed, but the thing is that.. ( I may be wrong ). Java started long ago. So a lot of frameworks were produced. Many are supported by now, because there are applications that still use it. But it does not mean that they are what you should use as a new start-up project. It is like Java 6 and Java 1.4. So as a start-up The Sixth version is probably better, isn't it? I may guess it's the same thing with web frameworks..